# Django Select2Widget not getting styled properly with crispy forms

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms, django-select2

I'm using the [django-select2](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package to implement Searchable Select on a ForeignKey field.
I was successful in getting the functionality to work by following the steps mentioned in the docs but I am having trouble with the styling.

To render my form I use crispy-forms. All the other widgets get rendered properly except the Select2Widget.

[image]

As can be seen in the above image, the height and width of the form element is not dynamic like other elements.

HTML code generated:

```
<div class=""> <select name="current_user" data-minimum-input-length="0" data-allow-clear="true" data-placeholder=""
        class="select2widget form-control django-select2" required id="id_current_user">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="">---------</option>
        <option value="4" selected>Arpita</option>

    </select> </div>
</div>
<div id="div_id_device_admin" class="form-group"> <label for="id_device_admin" class=" requiredField">
        Device admin<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
    <div class=""> <select name="device_admin" data-minimum-input-length="0" data-allow-clear="true" data-placeholder=""
            class="select2widget form-control django-select2" required id="id_device_admin">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="">---------</option>
            <option value="4" selected>Arpita</option>

        </select> </div>
</div>
```

This is how I set the widget in ModelForm.

```
def __init__(self, *args, in_org, **kwargs):
       ...
        self.fields['current_user'].widget = Select2Widget()
        self.fields['current_user'].queryset = in_org.user_set.all()
```

I feel this is mostly an issue with CSS styling and I am unable to figure out the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are looking for a solution (though I think it's not the best),

you can fix the layout issue by passing `attrs={'data-width': '100%'}`

e.g.

```
self.fields['current_user'].widget = Select2Widget(attrs={'data-width': '100%'})
```

or

```
current_user = forms.ChoiceField(
    widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
        model=User,
        search_fields=['username__istartswith'],
        attrs={'data-width': '100%'},
    ),
)
```